# Should my API show seconds when I am not taking seconds in input?

Tags: rest

I am designing a web page in which a user enters time in hh:mm format. As you can see that he is not entering seconds but, in the database, time is stored in hh:mm:ss format. So, by default, 00 is added for seconds. So, if a user entered 04:26, in the database it will be stored as 04:26:00. Now if I try to get this data using an API I will get the time as 04:26:00 in the response body because this is what is stored in the database. Is this correct because the user is not entering seconds? Besides, it can be a problem in post request where the request body can consist of 04:26:37. Now I can simply ignore the seconds but I want to know will that be a good restful design?

Answer (score 0):

> Now if I try to get this data using an API I will get the time as 04:26:00 in the response body because this is what is stored in the database. Is this correct because the user is not entering seconds?

You can format the data before returning it in the response body, and remove the seconds so that the user sees the value as he/she had entered it.

> Besides, it can be a problem in post request where the request body can consist of 04:26:37. Now I can simply ignore the seconds but I want to know will that be a good restful design?

You can either return an error when the input value contains seconds, or round the input value to the nearest minute, depending on the behavior you want to give to your application

Comment: I can format or I can leave as it is what should be a restful design?

Comment: I think it's better to format the input and output data

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Should I show the time as 04:26:00 or 04:26 in the response body?

Comment: I meant to change the output format to 04:26 so that the user sees the value as entered

Comment: When the user will make a get request, he will get the data in hh:mm:ss format because this is how it is stored in the database.

Comment: Yes I understood but you probably can add some code to edit what you read in the database before returning it to the user. I don't know what code you use but this is the solution

Comment: I get the data based on the username of the user and also there are other fields also not to mention multiple records also. You mean after getting the data I should apply some logic that strips off seconds from the time. Right?

Comment: Yes exaclty, this should be the best according to me